# Имитировать переход на сайт от лица сервера

Tags: php, curl

Есть ссылка на сайт, перейдя по которой на сайте выполняется определенное действие. На этот сайт открыт доступ только некоторым ip (моему серверу) и моему браузеру.
Если перейти по ссылке - выдаст json ответ и выполнится определенное действие на сайте (обнуление статистики).

Я хочу сделать возможность для пользователей выполнять это действие. Просто разрешить им переход по ссылке нельзя (у всех ip разный), тогда я решил сделать чтобы просто выполнялся запрос (cURL), с ip сервера на ссылку.

Запрос выполняется, пользователь получает json ответ, но на сайте сброс статистики не происходит.

Код которым делаю запрос к сайту

```
shell_exec('curl -s --digest -u логин:пароль http://сайт.ру/api.json?action=resetstats');
```

Что я делаю не так?  как сделать правильно?

Comment: А зачем именно shell_exec?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашим словам - то ошибка где-то в логике сброса, т.к. ответ в JSON же приходит, ну или это мистика :).

Для начала попробуйте сделать запроса через php curl, а не через shell_exec, и посмотрите что приходит в `$resp`

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://сайт.ру/api.json?action=resetstats');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'логин:пароль'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```